# How it works without security:access-denied-handler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to SPRING framework . I am learning spring security. I was trying to catch AccessDeniedException if wrong user login.

I made denied.jsp page and in my security-context.xml,

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="permitAll"/>
```

In my ErrorHandler , i handle this exception

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ErrorHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(AccessDeniedException.class)
    public String DeniedExceptionHandler(){
        return "denied";
    }

}
```

Now , when i run server , and wrong user log-in it shows me denied.jsp

Everything works fine the way i want but i have a doubt that how Spring knows which is  denied page to be showed up ? I mean i am **not** providing this

```
<security:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" /> ?
```

Why it works fine?

Appreciate your reply

Answer (score 0):

The controller always returns view name when you return string in method of controller.

The string you returned `denied` tells the view resolver to find `denied.jsp`

That's why it is working in your case.